# how to check query params are null or empty in apache camel

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel

I am trying to use camel-restlet-2.14.0 to call an external REST service. The call to the rest service will depends on the query parameters passed by the user.i am trying to do this using the xml configuration.

```
<spring:camelContext trace="true">
        <spring:route id="countries-fetch-route">
            <spring:from uri="restlet:/verifyTest?restletMethod=GET">
            </spring:from>
            <spring:choice>
                <spring:when>
                    <spring:simple>{header.abc} != null &amp;&amp; {header.pqr} != null</spring:simple>     
                    <spring:to uri="restlet:http://localhost:10080/TestRESTfulService/api/v1/av/verify/abc?abc={header.abc}&amp;pqr={header.pqr}"></spring:to>
                </spring:when>
            </spring:choice>
           <spring:transform>
                <spring:simple>${body}</spring:simple>
            </spring:transform>
        </spring:route>
    </spring:camelContext>
```

if anybody can help me to check the headers(query Params) that would be really helpful

Comment: The start token is ${ and not {. So it should be ${header.abc}

Comment: @ClausIbsen i believe camel restlet wont recognize query params sent from spring mvc. When i am logging the headers it wont have the query param as seperate header, rather it gives CamelHttpQuery as a one single header, which contains all the query Parameters.

Comment: Query parameters are **not** the same as headers. You need to parse the URI to get the parameters (lots of choices on this). Then, you could add these parameters as headers for convenience in your routing.

Comment: @AdamHawkes so deos that means that there is no way you can do the xml configuration and still acheive the target???

Comment: Whether you use the XML or Java DSLs,  the contents of the URI do not automatically create new headers on the exchange. You would need to code this behavior yourself.